# Fallo ejecucion script

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tengo un Script en javascript que se me ejecuta correctamente en Firefox pero no en IE11, se trata de que tras un determinado if, se me abra un pop up:
En php tengo el siguiente código:

```
if(xxxx){echo '<body onload="abrir()">';}
```

En la página html de donde se referencia el formulario al php en head tengo lo siguiente:

```
<script>
  function abrir(){  
    window.open('popup.html', '', 'top=500, left=500, width=700,height=700');
  }
</script>`
```

Ya he habilitado  los popup en ie11, y no entiendo muy bien por qué no se me ejecuta.

Comment: ¿Por qué no revisas el inspector de Javascript y nos cuentas qué error te muestra, si es que muestra alguno?

Comment: La doc dice con respecto a los parámetros: *The string **must not contain any whitespace**, and each feature name and its value must be separated by a comma*. Como prevención, yo llenaría también el segundo parámetro. Prueba de este modo: **`window.open('popup.html', 'Test', 'top=500,left=500,width=700,height=700');`**.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que necesitas poner un titulo obligatoriamente en los parametros de la función open
así:

```
<script>
  function abrir(){  
    window.open('popup.html', 'TITULO', 'top=500, left=500, width=700,height=700');
  }
</script>
```